# How to store many products in one invoice?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im storing data in my ticket table which its basically a repair-product invoice. So a customer sends a product by filling in a form with the product data. But the customer may send one product or three porudcts or x amount of products to our lab.

I have my products table with some fields such as:

```
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('ptype_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('model_id');
        $table->foreign('model_id')->references('id')->on('models');
```

How can i do so that in my tickets table i can store several products?

This are some of my tickets fields:

```
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cuenta_id');
        $table->foreign('cuenta_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('contact_id');
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('statusTicket_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('ptype_id');
        $table->foreign('ptype_id')->references('id')->on('ptypes');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brand_id');
```

And i have this intermidiate table called detalles_tickets:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('detalles_tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('ticket_id');
        $table->foreign('ticket_id')->references('id')->on('tickets');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->integer('serial_number');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->text('commentary');
        $table->string('file')->nullable(); //La direccion de la imagen que se sube del remito
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Doing this im only storing one product.

This is part of my ticketController store method:

```
    $ticket->ptype_id = $request->$ptype_id;
    $ticket->brand_id = $request->$brand_id;
    $ticket->model_id = $request->$model_id;
    $ticket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to improve your architecture. The best way to achieve what you want is to have two models Products and Invoices and a mid table which has a many to many relationship that looks like this:

invoice_id product_id quantity

So you can get all the products that were assigned to that invoice no matter if they are zero or twenty and you might want your quantity.